# Requests gets dashes, while the same webpage gives me the page with all details?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

Why would the `driver` get all the details but `requests` doesn't get all the details.

I am trying to cut down the time it takes for me to get quotes from the website using `driver`. Facing the following problem which I can't find a way around.

```
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=AUROPHARMA&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=28MAR2018&type=-&strike=-'
raw_page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page, "lxml")
soup.find("span",{"id":"lastPrice"}).text
```

Gives

> '--'

```
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=AUROPHARMA&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=28MAR2018&type=-&strike=-'
raw_page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page, "lxml")
soup.find("span",{"id":"lastPrice"}).text
```

Gives

> '617.00'

I am not able to figure out if there is a way around this.

Comment: Hi Keyur, yes it is a duplicate. Removing this question.